# Retry connection postgres Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am using a postgres database for my express web server.
I am using the 'pg' library to execute queries on this database.

Here is my connection method :

```
const db = new Client({
    user: 'xxx',
    host: 'xxx',
    database: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    port: xxx,
})
db.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('connection error', err.stack)
    } else {
        console.log('connected')
    }
```

Then to execute a request I do this:

```
db.query(MY_REQUEST, function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('hello/world', {
                title: 'Hello',
                data: data.rows
            });
        });`
```

It all works perfectly. But after several minutes without using my website, my connection to the db times out, and I get the following error:

```
node:events:355
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^
Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:73)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:484:28)
at Connection.emit (node:events:378:20)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:58:12)
at Socket.emit (node:events:378:20)
at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:665:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
at Client._handleErrorEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:319:10)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:149:16)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:484:28)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:665:12)
```

How could I do to reconnect automatically when the connection is cut or when a request fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach an `error`-handler in order to prevent the unhandled error crashing your app. It's as simple as:

```
db.on('error', e => {
  console.error('DB error', e);
});
```

As to why the error happens we need more details, looks like it could be a connection reset due to idle-timeout?

Comment: Yes it is a timeout when the connection is inactive, I want to keep this behavior, I just want that when I need to make a request, my server automatically reconnects to the db and execute the request.

Comment: Using your solution I was able to reconnect but how can I do to rerun the request which triggered the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to control if you're connected to database or not, before you continue with your main function.

Create a function for controlling `database connection status`, `reconnecting` etc. and before you run a database related function, first start that middle function and wait for result, after that you can continue using database again.

If you want(which should be prefered way mostly), create that `middle function as an async function` and `return a promise`, when using that function `wait for that function`.